# .wav file into S3 bucket instance

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to upload a .wav file to s3.
My currently put_object code looks like this:

```
client.put_object(
ACL='public-read',
Bucket='test',
Key='test_folder/' + file_name,
ContentType = 'audio/x-wav',
Body='test_folder/music/' + file_name,
StorageClass='STANDARD_IA'
)
```

I'm uploading it successfully, but when I try to download it and play, I get an error:

> Could not determine type of stream

What arguments do I need to pass in order to tell S3 that it's a sound .wav file? When I tried to upload it using boto.s3 using bucket.new_key(key_name) and set_content_from_file, it worked perfectly, but I couldn't set the StorageClass using that function.

Thanks.

Comment: `Body='test_folder/music/' + file_name,` should setting *this literal string* as the object payload, rather than the contents of the file you're intending to read.  You should find that the object you're uploading is very small, because that's all it contains.

Comment: Incidentally, just to be sure: you do understand that `STANDARD_IA` costs **more** than `STANDARD` when the object is downloaded more than once per month, right?  `STANDARD_IA` saves money on storage, but charges a "data retrieval" fee for each download... hence the name *"infrequent access."*  You don't want to use this storage class for objects accessed more frequently than about once per month.

Comment: Hi, the object (sound) is less then 50MB, most of the time it's 10MB. I know about what Standard_IA is, that's why I wanna use it, as soon as I upload the files, they will be downloaded about once 1-2 months. What should I do to embed the object into the Body argument?